# Creating directory with permissions

Tags: c#, create-directory

My goal is to create a directory named "Logs", inside the user profile directory: lets call it - C:\Users\UserX.
When I'm logged in as UserX, which is also listed as an administrator of the current machine, the directory: C:\Users\UserX\Logs is created successfully.
However, when I'm logged in as UserY or any other user who is not UserX and not listed as an administrator of the machine, I get a permission exception upon creating the mentioned directory (C:\Users\UserY\Logs)
Is it possible to create a directory named "Logs" in the path C:\Users\UserY\Logs, when UserY is not an administrator of the machine and if so how can I make it via code (C#)?
My current code looks like the following:

```
        var rootFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

        var logsFolder = Path.Combine(rootFolder, "Logs");
        if (!Directory.Exists(logsFolder))
        {
            var dirSec = new DirectorySecurity(rootFolder, AccessControlSections.All);
            var procInfo = Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo;
            var domainName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(procInfo.Domain) ? Environment.UserDomainName : procInfo.Domain;
            var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(procInfo.UserName) ? Environment.UserName : procInfo.UserName;
            userName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", domainName, userName);
            dirSec.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(userName, FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, AccessControlType.Allow));
            dirSec.SetAuditRule(new FileSystemAuditRule(userName, FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, AuditFlags.Failure));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logsFolder);
        }
```

But then, if Directory Logs does not exist in "C:\Users\UserY" and UserY is not an administrator of the machine, I get a permission exception upon creating the mentioned directory as I've already mentioned. Is it possible for UserY to create such a directory in "C:\Users\UserY", and if so, how can it be done via code?

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? Console, Windows Service, WCF, ASP.NET MVC/Web Api?

Comment: Shouldn't you really be creating it in a suitable sub folder of the user's AppData folder.

Comment: @George Onofrei It's Windows Application (WPF). This code is writen in App.xaml.cs.
CompuChip - Do you mean "C:\Users\MyApplicationName\AppData"?
If so, no, because I want the application to take individual data per user when there might be many users using the same machine. They all use my app, and I want each user to get his individual info under his user profile folder. Of course, if it is not possible, I might consider your idea. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be an option to assign rights to users for a folder?
E.g.: UserY is not Admin, but you can say that FolderA has special permissions for UserY, in particular Write permission.